# MKMapView - render user from information returned by web service

Tags: ios, web-services, asynchronous, location

I'm using a web service to retrieve user label and annotation details. The web service is called when the view loads. After the information is retrieved, I now have the details and am ready to update the map with them. I'd like to update the user with the new title and custom pin type.

In the meantime, because the service is asynchronous, the map has already rendered, so the user is already drawn represented with a blue pulsing dot. In other words, at the time the map is rendering, the web service hasn't yet returned, so the new information isn't available.

The issues:

- preventing the user from initially rendering
- changing the user's title and pin type when the information is received

I understand there isn't a way to get the map to refresh on demand, but to instead remove and add annotations. But it won't let me do that with `MKUserLocation`. So an additional issue:

- how is the map updated if there are no annotations, just the user?

I've reviewed SO and there doesn't seem to be any answer to this specific question. Sure, if the details are already hardcoded in the app, no problem, but this isn't the case.

Comment: I've not used MKMap classes very much, so I have a more generic idea:  how about, after the web request completes, building another map view offscreen, then swapping with the visible one?  I'm guessing it will build quickly because the imagery is probably cached.

Comment: Interesting, maybe if I initially hide the map, and then show it after the web service loads. Trying it now. - Nope, still tries to render before web service loads.

Comment: Step two would be to leave it enabled and update position/zoom of the offscreen one just before replacing.

Comment: I'm thinking the solution might be dynamic view creation, but this seems so clunky. I would hope there is an easier solution.

Comment: Found it - `setShowUserLocation` to `NO` (either in code or IB), then when the data comes in set it to `YES`. `viewForAnnotation` will then be called after the data is loaded.

Comment: That's good.  You can write that as an answer and mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can disable it via `setShowUserLocation:NO` in either `viewDidLoad` or IB, then when the web service returns A) set to `YES`, or B) add the user as a regular annotation. Would recommend B, then you don't need to write extra user handling code in the callback. Once you go custom pin, you lose the blue pulsing rings anyway, so might as well make it easier on yourself.